# Laravel 5 wildcard files including

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, wildcard

I have multiple *.html files I need to include in my new project, all these files are numbered - 1.html, 2.html and so on. Now I'd like to use wildcard routing like mysite/item/1 redirecting to view with content included from 1.html file.

How do I do this? I'm not really asking for the code itself, but rather for pointing me in the right direction. I bet the solution is incredibly easy yet I can not figure it out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('mysite/item/{view_name}', function($id) {
    return view($view_name);
});
```

Just pass the name of the view as a parameter as you're doing in the example. Then pass that parameter to the view() function..

Answer (score 0):

where goes $id?
Meanwhile I did it a little bit different way, more clear for me:

```
Route::get('showItem/{id}', function($id) {
    return view('showItem')->withId($id);
});
```

I prefer sending variable through ->withVariable($variable) , it seems more readable for me in later times. But maybe it's just me ;)

Thank you for the answer, Sturm!